# computing characteristic polynomial of hyperplane arrangement

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, vector-spaces

The following problem comes from Richard Stanley's $\textit{Enumerative Combinatorics}$ vol. 1, 2nd ed. It is problem 114 (c) in Chapter 3.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a hyperplane arrangement in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $x_i=x_j$ and $x_i=2x_j$ for $1\leq i<j\leq n$ and $x_i=0$ for some $1\leq i \leq n$. Show that $\chi_{\mathcal{A}}=(x-1)(x-(n-1))^{n-1}$.

I want to apply the Finite Field Method to compute the characteristic polynomial, which is shown below. I will mention that $L(\mathcal{A})$ is the lattice which consists of all nonempty intersections of hyperplanes in $\mathcal{A}$.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of how I could possibly count the number of hyperplanes such that $x_i\neq x_j$ and $x_i\neq 2x_j$ for all $i<j$?? Any ideas are greatly appreciated!